# SVG Grid of rects translucent in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg

I have a problem with a grid of `rects` in an SVG.

Here is my code over at jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swpcpvxL/

It is supposed to make a square by plotting one pixel at a time. I use a 1 by 1 SVG `rect` to plot a pixel.

```
var svg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

for (var y = 50; y <= 150; ++y) {
  for (var x = 50; x <= 150; ++x) {
    var r = Math.floor((x + y) / 250);
    var g = Math.floor((Math.sin(x/10.0) + 1) * x);
    var b = Math.floor((Math.sin(y/10.0) + 1) * x);
    var color = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";

    var k = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
    k.setAttribute("x", x);
    k.setAttribute("y", y);
    k.setAttribute("width", "1");
    k.setAttribute("height", "1");
    k.setAttribute("style", "fill: " + color);
    svg.appendChild(k);
  }
}
```

My issue is that on Firefox the `rect` don't plot correctly. They show up the wrong color (washed out) and are actually translucent. I think the issue is that Firefox is doing anti-aliasing or something on the `rect`s instead of just plotting the `rect` right on the pixel I want. I also tested on IE - it doesn't have this problem and the code works correctly. I don't have Chrome to test with.

I uploaded an image of what it looks like for me in Firefox [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6nuH.png).

As you can see in the image, I can see the circles through the `rect`s. This is not what I want at all!

How can I fix the Firefox problem? Or is there a better way to generate and plot a bitmap in a SVG like this? I've noticed that this method is a bit slow, so maybe there is a better approach.

Thanks!

Comment: For what it worths, I can't repro on my mac, unless I do zoom the page, and in that case, chrome has the exact same behavior, due to antialiasing on half pixel positions.

Comment: if you want to draw pixel by pixel it might be more performant to use a canvas. bunch of 1px rects sounds fairly expensive to draw.

Comment: This does seem like a bug in Firefox. You should [report it to Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Don't report it, it's not a bug it's antialiasing. Use shape-rendering: crispEdges to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem in my Firefox too. It does look like a blending problem of some sort. You can also see the image "flicker" if you move the window around or resize it.

A work around is to plot each rect as a 2x2 box, instead of a 1x1. So the only change is this:

```
k.setAttribute("width", "2");
k.setAttribute("height", "2");
```

You still step on the X and Y by one pixel at a time.

That way each rect overlaps the one on each side by 1 pixel. It will make your entire 100 square one pixel bigger to the right and bottom. You may want to shift the origin to compensate, if you use this method and care about that.